# C# , JSON Serializer and Deserializer on Class Dynamic Attributes

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Hi I have an existing class called attributes (below) with a base set of static attribute. I am using this class to Serialize and Deserialize with JavaScriptSerializer

```
public class attributes
{
public string static1 {get; set;}
public string static2 {get; set;}
public string static3 {get; set;}
}
```

My current Sample JSON based on this class attribute above

```
{
  "static1": "val1",
  "static2": "val2",
  "static3": "val3"
}
```

I need to do a modification to my class so that I keep the base set and expand this class to accept a new format. I will be receiving a new JSON from a Vendor where they will append a dynamic section of attributes ( in my sample JSON below from 1 to N). This way the existing base set of static attributes will be accessible AND also provide a dynamic list of attributes ( which can vary from 0 to n - meaning it can be the same JSON as the static if there are no additional attributes available or can have the 3 static attribute + a number of other additional attribute )

New JSON with both static and dynamic

```
{
  "static1": "val1",
  "static2": "val2",
  "static3": "val3",
  "dynamic1": "dyn1",
           .
           .
  "dynamicN": "dynN"
}
```

Can anyone provide some input on how to best represent this new class GIVEN the new requirement ( where we may have more attributes in the JSON i obtain ) ?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you should be using `Dictionary<string,string>`, frankly, and just pull out the ones you *expect* manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do `dynamic` object to manually parsed your `json` result.

something like this(using Newtonsoft.Json):

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);
foreach (dynamic item in json)
{
   //manually get the values
   var static1= item["static1"];
   var static2= item["static2"];
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a [dynamics type variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) to get the information of the JSON that aren't mapped in your class

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string data = "{ "+
"\"0\": {" +
"   \"sku\": \"trickeye\", " +
"   \"calendar_type\": \"date\", " +
"   \"voucher_type\": \"Instant Voucher\"   " +
"},"+
" \"1\": { " +
"   \"sku\": \"lovemuseum\", " +
"   \"calendar_type\": \"date\", " +
"   \"voucher_type\": \"Instant Voucher\"} " +
"}";
dynamic dictionary = json.DeserializeObject(data);

var firstDefinition = dictionary["0"] as Dictionary<string, object>;

Console.WriteLine(firstDefinition);
Console.WriteLine(dictionary["0"]["sku"].ToString());
```

[image]